# consult sql join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I try make this consult in sql, but i dont know how.

I have a tables of product shops.

And i want a table similar this:

```
tshirt  | jeans   | number sells
---------------------------------------
tshirt1 | jean1   |   5
tshirt1 | jean2   |   4
tshirt1 | jean3   |   0
.............................
tshirt1 | jeanN   |   3
```

This information i have in other table where i have shopping.
This table have a code of users and a row for buy with one product.

```
codeUser   product buy
-------------------------
1           tshirt1
1           jeans1
2           jeans2
...............
```

I want know many people buy a tshirt1 and also buy one product of category2.

I have a view with product filter by category, example tshirt; and other view equals but filter other category, example jeans.

I need this view??, or i need other view??

I dont know how I will do the query

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to generate all the rows using a cross join. Then bring in the customer information.

I think it looks like this:

```
select t.product as tshirt, j.product as jeans,
       count(distinct bj.codeUser)
from (select distinct product from buys where product like 'tshirt%') t cross join
     (select distinct product from buys where product like 'jeans%') j left join
     buys bt
     on bt.product = t.product left join
     buys bj
     on bj.product = j.product and
        bj.codeuser = bt.codeuser
group by t.product as tshirt, j.product;
```